# increasing the file limit of montage

Tags: imagemagick-montage

`montage -list resource` says that the file limit is 768. I'd like to change that to, say, 10001. To facilitate this I edited `vim /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`, changing this line:

```
<!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="10001"/> -->
```

To this:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="file" value="10001"/>
```

But when I rerun `montage -list resource` it still says that the file limit is 768.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to be root to change it. If you are on a shared server, the hosting provider needs to make the change.. You can only make it more restrictive, not less. The ISP can make it anything.

Comment: @fmw42 - I am root when I change it. Testament to this is the fact that my changes to `<policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="16GiB"/>` stuck (well that's what I changed it too - not what I changed it from). `montage -list resource` reflects this. It just isn't reflecting changes I make to the file resource.

Comment: Then you should inquire on the Imagemagick GIF forum at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6 for IM 6 and at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick for IM 7